# PyQt4: Reorder Ok and Cancel buttons in the QDialogButtonBox

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt4

How can I override the standard order of buttons in the QDialogButtonBox class?

It seems that PyQt [follows some kind of standard based on the platform it runs on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598313/order-of-push-buttons-on-different-platforms-qdialogbuttonbox).

At the moment Cancel is on the left and Ok on the right (I'm on CentOS 6):

[image]

but my users find it confusing and counter to what they're used to and have asked me to swap them:

[image]

This is how I create the box:

```
    self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self)
    self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
```

Comment: Did you try using `QDialogButtonBox::AcceptRole` and `QDialogButtonBox::RejectRole` ?

Comment: @Thomas I've used `buttonBox.accepted` and `buttonBox.rejected` to link to the respective methods I want called when Ok or Cancel is pressed. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Not totally, what happen if you try with ` addButton()`  instead of setStdBtn ?

Comment: I haven't but I was wondering if I could avoid doing this? As I understand it, using `setStandardButtons` sets up buttons with signals that I can link to straight-away (with `accepted` and `rejected`), rather than having to customise them to behave as Cancel and OK buttons which I will need to do if I used `addButton`.

Comment: If you don't need the standard ordering you don't need QDialogButtonBox also.

Comment: @fasked It's just that it's quite easy to set up using it which is why I went for it, I've only just started programming in Qt and this is a lot easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought about changing the direction in the layout containing the buttons:

```
buttonBox.layout().setDirection(QtGui.QBoxLayout.RightToLeft)
```

In the following example:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox()
buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
buttonBox.layout().setDirection(QtGui.QBoxLayout.RightToLeft) # with this line the order of the buttons swap

buttonBox.show()
app.exec_()
```

it reverses the order for me (If RightToLeft doesn't work, also try `QtGui.QBoxLayout.LeftToRight`).

Comment: But this will change more things than just the buttons?

Comment: @FinalContest Is a QDialogButtonBox used for other stuff than only buttons?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. This will not still necessarily work for >=3 buttons, but might do the job for two, yeah. The most ideal solution would be to "define the order".

Comment: @FinalContest Then I would follow the suggestion of Thomas in a comment to the question and use `addButton()` and add buttons manually in the order I like.